# Wordpress WP_Query Search resutls page. Unwanted search term

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page'  =>-1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => $order_key,
    'tax_query'       => array(
               'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy1,
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $type,
                'operator'=> $type_operator,
                'include_children' => false
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy2,
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $location,
                'operator'=> $location_operator,
                'include_children' => false
            ),
        ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($query);
```

But when I check the var_dump, here it is:

```
object(WP_Query)#492 (48) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(12) "$post_type"
    ["posts_per_page"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["orderby"]=>
    string(14) "meta_value_num"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(18) "$order_key"
    ["tax_query"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["relation"]=>
      string(3) "AND"
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(20) "$taxonomy1"
        ["field"]=>
        string(2) "id"
        ["terms"]=>
        string(3) "819"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(18) "$taxonomy2"
        ["field"]=>
        string(2) "id"
        ["terms"]=>
        string(3) "167"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(68) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(12) "$post_type"
    ["posts_per_page"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["orderby"]=>
    string(14) "meta_value_num"
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(18) "$order_key"
    ["tax_query"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["relation"]=>
      string(3) "AND"
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(20) "$taxonomy1"
        ["field"]=>
        string(2) "id"
        ["terms"]=>
        string(3) "819"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(18) "$taxonomy2"
        ["field"]=>
        string(2) "id"
        ["terms"]=>
        string(3) "167"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
  ["date_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["request"]=>
  string(901) "SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (819) 
  AND 
  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (167)
) AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '$order_key'
) AND wp_posts.post_type = '$post_type' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$search%' OR wp_posts.ID IN ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%$search%' ) OR wp_posts.ID IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id WHERE t.name LIKE '%$search%' ) OR wp_posts.post_content RLIKE '[[:<:]]$search[[:>:]]' )  GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC "
```

Above query is running on search results page using a custom hook. But I am trying to show custom post type based on the input given by user (taxonomy1 and taxonomy2). These results will be shown before the normal search results.

Everything is fine except the search keyword is automatically added to WP_Query. I didn't inculded 's' in the arguments, but in the final query, it is there. Any one help me please on how to avoid search term to be included in WP_Query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run **<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>** anywhere in your script? Perhaps before or after your query? REF: ***https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inclusion of search term is caused by some filter in other plugin. Site uses WP Jobs Manager plugin and it is causing this issue. So I have to use `'suppress_filters' => true` in my query args which fixed the issue.